# Why do some apps have no close button?

Tags: release-loki, design, user-interface

In Elementary, some apps have a close button while others... don't. Why is that? Is that a bug or a deliberate design decision? I can still close the app by right-clicking the title bar and clicking close but that is much more tedious than it needs to be IMO.

For example, please see below picture:

[image: settings window without any close button]

Comment: Just checked to see if I could reproduce the issue and my system settings dialogue has an 'X' close button on the left of the window bar.

Comment: @Seth any idea how to diagnose the problem or reset whatever settings apply? This looks like a bug and I'm going to report it shortly.

Comment: my first troubleshooting step would be to create a new testing user account, and see if you can reproduce using that account. Also try a fresh install of Loki on another computer or VM and see if it occurs there too.

Comment: I had a similar idea. I found out that most applications store their settings in the ~/.config folder so I backed it up and then renamed it. After a reboot, I lost all my settings but at least the close buttons returned.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to some settings that got messed up. I cleaned the `~/.config` folder (after backing it up of course), and then rebooted. The problem went away. I am still not sure which exact setting was responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure it will help you or not. Install Tweaks.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks  
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

**System Settings-->Tweaks-->Appearance-->Layout**

Select an option.

[image]

Comment: although I did not try elementary-tweaks, I did try and alter the position of close and maximize buttons through command line but that didn't help.